# Assign read.csv with some set parameters to a name, in order to pass it to a function

Tags: r, function

I want to read multiple files. To do this I use a generic function `read_list`

```
read_list(file_list, read_fun)
```

Assigning different read function to the argument `read_fun` I can read different kinds of files, i.e. `read.csv` for reading `csv` files, `read_dta` for STATA files, etc.

Now, I need to read some `csv` files where the first four lines need to be skipped. Thus, instead than passing `read.csv` as an argument to `read_list`, I would like to pass `read.csv` with the `skip` argument set to 4. Is it possible to do this in R? I tried

```
my_read_csv  <- function(...){
read.csv(skip = 4, ...)
}
```

It seems to work, but I would like to confirm that this is the right way to do it. I think that functions being objects in R is a fantastic and very powerful feature of the language, but I'm not very familiar with R closures and scoping rules, thus I don't want to inadvertently make some big mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply rewrite your `read_list` to add the unnamed argument qualifier `...` at the end and then replace the call to
`read_fun(file)` with `read_fun(file, ...)`.

This will allow you to write the following syntax:

```
read_list(files, read.csv, skip = 4)
```

wich will be equivalent to using your current `read_list` with a cusom read function:

```
read_list(files, function(file)read.csv(file, skip = 4))
```

Also, be aware that `read_list` sounds awfully lot like a "reinvent the wheel" function. If you describe the behaviour of `read_list` a little more, I can expand.
Possible alternatives may be

```
read_list <- function(files, read_fun, ...)lapply(files, read_fun, ...)
# in this case read_list is identical to lapply
read_list <- function(files, read_fun, ...)do.call(rbind, lapply(files, read_fun, ...))
# This will rbind() all the files to one data.frame
```

Comment: your proposal is interesting, but I'm not sure it's general. I mean, do I need to modify the `read_list` code if I want to pass a parameter different from `skip`? If so, then the response is not acceptable: it's clearly much more local to wrap `read.csv` in a different `my_read_csv` function each time I need to set a different parameter, than to modify `read_list` each time. Otherwise, your solution is optimal. I will test it and let you know.

Comment: @DeltaIV No you do not. You can pass any parameter to the underlying function.

Comment: Concerning the structure of `read_list`, of course it contains `lapply`, but it's superior because it allows me to assign a name to each data set, derived from the file name. This is very useful because in my application file names contain useful information which I then parse before the `do.call` step in another `merge_list` function. If you want to have a look at the code, my implementation is very similar to [this](http://www.brodrigues.co/2016/07/26/read-a-lot-of-datasets-at-once-with-r), with a few minor differences (tweaks related to my specific application).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `read_list` is specialized to your specific task in some way but you can use `lapply` along with `read.csv` to read a list of files:

```
# generate fake file names
files <- paste0('file_', 1:10, '.csv')

# Read files using lapply
dfs <- lapply(files, read.csv, skip = 4)
```

The third argument of `lapply` is `...` which allows you to pass additional arguments to the function you're applying. In this case, we can use `...` to pass the `skip = 4` argument to `read.csv`